# verifying login with norwegian letters

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I am having this really annoying problem on a php-site I am programming and hoping to tap into the well of knowledge that is stackoverflow to help overcome it.

The logic of the login verification is like this.

1. You register and a mail is sendt to you. The mail contains an url with your username and an id that will be matched up to an id stored under your user name in a table. (Via $_GET)
2. If the function finds 1 row with matching id and user name it will change verified to "yes" for that user.

This all works fine, until you use names with æ ø or å in them. Like Jørgen. The mail verification function was altered to accomodate for this, turning the url into something like

www.myphppage.com/index.php?login=j%F8rgen&id=62185505683314306498

I've made the php-function that checks sql print login and it prints correctly as Jørgen on the html-page. In the program **mysql workbench**, the name also displays correctly in the table.

If i try to **select * from `database`.`user_reg` WHERE login='{$login}'** however, it doesn't match and mysql_num_rows returns 0. If i try the same with just the id though, it matches and returns 1 like it should. I think the fault must lie in the query somewhere.

My index-page uses **charset=iso-8859-1** 
and my Database uses Latin-1_general ci

Help is appreciated

-Johann

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use base64_encode() function.

```
$url='www.myphppage.com/index.php?ver='.base64_encode($login.'|'.$id);
```

and then ...

```
$data=explode('|',base64_decode($_GET['ver']));
$login=$data[0];
$id=$data[1];
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks a lot. Now people with pesky pesky names like Jørgen and Søren can also enlist on my page.

Answer (score 0):

What is the char-set used to tlak to your mysql server?

I had a similar problem, php script in utf-8, generated page in utf-8, database in utf-8, but connexion between script and mysql in latin_1 (iso-8859-1).

I solved it using the `SET character_set_connection` command after initialising my PDO object. [charset-connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)

Comment: Don’t set the character set directly, use the corresponding API method instead.

Comment: You mean by setting `charset=thecharset` in the constructor?

Comment: I tried setting it by using 

if(!($fix = @ mysql_query("SET character_set_connection= latin1_general_cs;",$this->connection)))

Don't know if that's right. But a combination of this and the Base64 worked. How would you set character connection? At the creation of the database?

Comment: You can use the mysql mysql_set_charset api function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php. Did it work with Base64 only or it is necessary to combinate those two fix?

Comment: It seems that the Base64 was the thing that did the trick, since my cryptic try at changing sql character set failed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that those characters are not automatically url-decoded by PHP's Magic Quotes, but other URL encoded parts have been decoded, thus using [`rawurldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) could potentially corrupt the message.  But if you had access to the original name value passed over (fully encoded), you could use `rawurlencode()` to get your characters.

But [magic quotes can only be disabled at the system level](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php), so this is an all or nothing deal (which sucks).